# How to get matplotlib working under IPython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

When I type

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

in my IPython notebook I get

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

Shouldn't be this module installed by default? Do I need to extra install it. If it is the case, how can I do it. I use virtual environment on Linux to install stuff (including IPython).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Python setup (2.7.3, Linux), I installed `matplotlib` as well as `IPython` via `pip`. `matplotlib` is available from the normal Python interpreter as well as from IPython (as expected). The order of installation does not matter.

And no, `IPython` should not have `matplotlib` installed by default, this does not make sense.

Comment: matplotlib is often available as a system package. for instance on Ubuntu, it's `python-matplotlib`

Comment: Right, but when working within a virtualenv or when dealing with a custom Python installation anyway, pip is a great way to install matplotlib. Also, especially regarding matplotlib it can be important to have access to a cutting-edge version. Don't want to miss features such as `tight_layout()` anymore.

Comment: point taken, but you chose a bad example - `tight_layout()` was introduced in v1.1, which was released in 2011, so any reasonable OS should already offer that. personally, on current Ubuntu I'm on 1.2.1

Answer (score 3):

Matplotlib is not installed by default, there are instructions on the [IPython install page](http://ipython.org/install.html) to install on linux:

> Optionally install additional tools for scientific computing: On
>   Ubuntu or other Debian-based distributions, type at the shell:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib python-scipy python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
> ```
>
> On Fedora 18 and newer related distributions, use:
>
> ```
> sudo yum install python-matplotlib scipy python-pandas sympy
> python-nose
> ```

Though if you are using a python virtualenv, you should be able to use `pip install matplotlib` when you are in the virual environment.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and I do not have root privileges. So, I use virtual environment to install locally. I tried `pip intall matplotlib` in my virtual environment and it worked.

Comment: Good point, sudo not needed in the virtual environment, have updated

Answer (score 1):

In case you are trying on Python 3, you can install it using:

`python3-matplotlib`

Hope it helps!